# Show time in 24 or 12 hours format depending on timezone

Tags: php, time, timezone

Is there any way to check if time is usually displayed in a 24hrs or 12hrs (meridiem(AM/PM)) format having the [**time zones**](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The *timezone* is pretty irrelevant here, what's relevant is the cultural conventions, mostly the **locale** used. E.g. `en_US` vs. `en_UK` vs. `ja_JP` etc. There may be several different locales used in a specific timezone, so there's no useful 1:1 mapping there. I think you should base time formatting on your user's locale preference, not on timezones.

Comment: I was hoping for such a list. But ok. :) Thanks

Comment: Well, take the example of something like Belgium, where there are at least three officially recognised languages used, each of which probably have their slight differences in date/time formatting. (In this particular case they probably don't differ in AM/PM use, but it's not unthinkable either.) You'd want to vary the overall formatting based on the locale, not the timezone.

Comment: Ok, I will let the user choose their preferences in the account settings then. Good example!

Comment: Also, consider I might be an English speaking US tourist visiting Japan.  I might want to switch my time zone to `Asia/Tokyo`, but I most likely won't switch my computer's locale to `ja_JP` (unless I also want to read text in Japanese).